# Про хостинг бота дискорда

Tags: python, discord, бот

Вот команды которые я вел:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import keep_alive

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('работает')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id ==  987735962232700970:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Ког загружен")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не создатель бота")

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id ==  987735962232700970:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Ког загружен")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не создатель бота")

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id ==  987735962232700970:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Ког загружен")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не создатель бота")

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

keep_alive.keep_alive()

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']

# Подключение бота
client.run(os.environ.get('TOKEN'), bot=True, reconnect =True)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord
```

Comment: `No module named 'discord` — вам нужен перевод этой фразы?

Comment: нет мне нужно решить проблему

Comment: если переведёте, то получите руководство по решению проблемы.

Comment: установите модуль discord

Comment: Заголовок вопроса "Про хостинг..." однако нет никакой информации про хостинг. Дополните вопрос, потому что сейчас это выглядит так, будто бы у вас просто чужой код не запускается

Answer (score 0):

чтобы решить проблему, вам нужно установить модуль дискорд.

установить его можно путем написания команды в терминале `pip install discord.py`, и после этого ошибка должна исправиться.